# Javascript Regular Expression "Single Space Character"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning javascript and I am analyzing existing codes.

In my JS reference book, it says to search on a single space use "`\s`"?

But I have came across the code

```
obj.match(/Kobe Bryant/);
```

Instead of using `\s`, it uses the actual space?

Why doesn't this generate an error?

Comment: The MDN RegExp page is a good resource for JS regular expression and dealing with the `RegExp` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The character class `\s` does not just contain the space character but also other [Unicode white space characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#endnote_equivalent_s). `\s` is equivalent to this character class:

```
[\t\n\v\f\r \u00a0\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u200b\u2028\u2029\u3000]
```

Comment: +1, probably took you longer than the others to fetch the link :-)

Comment: It is incredibly important for anybody who is encoding data to consider the difference between "the one true space char, ' ', and 'any whitespace user might send me'.  \s is almost always what you want, but be careful... if you are encoding binary data, be sure to match only 'spacebar' `\u0020`

Comment: The link is no longer valid. Could you please update it? I'm really interested. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

No.  It is perfectly legal to include a literal space in a regex.

However, it's not equivalent - `\s` will include any whitespace character, including tabs, non-breaking spaces, half-width spaces and other characters, whereas a literal space will only match the regular space character.

Answer (score 10):

`\s` matches any whitespace character, including tabs etc. Sure you can use a literal space also without problems. Just like you can use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` to denote any digit. However, keep in mind that `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d` whereas the literal space is a subset of `\s`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to normal spaces, `\s` matches different kinds of white space characters, including tabs (and possibly newline characters, according to configuration). That said, matching with a normal space is certainly valid, especially in your case where it seems you want to match a name, which is normally separated by a normal space.

Answer (score 0):

\xA0 is also a white space, especially a non-breaking space.
We did have an issue with Quill Editor when we paste a plain text with spaces from notepad++.
The white space in JS \xA0 is a white space but does not match a normal white space \u0020 (' ').