# Optimize given regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Following regex replaces `" >" or " > " or "> "` character with `"/"`.

```
tempKeyword = tempKeyword.replace(/( > )|( >)|(> )/g,'/');
```

How can I make this better?

Thanks!

Comment: Are those the *only* things it should match? What about ">" with no spaces on either side?

Comment: Yes, This are only cases in which it should match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a try with this one:

```
tempKeyword = tempKeyword.replace(/\s*>\s*/g,'/');
```

Edit 2 according to comment below:

```
tempKeyword = tempKeyword.replace(/(?:^|\S+\s)>(?:\s\S+|$)/g,'/');
```

Comment: This one is good. However, if @Bramha needs 0 or 1 space at the beginning and 0 or 1 space after > then it should be \s{0,1}>\s{0,1}.

Comment: It should be mentioned that space and *any white-space character*  are different things.

Also, as this RegEx matches a wider variety of cases and variable lengths, I'm assuming that OPs version is still more "optimized" than this.

Comment: the star would match 0 or more, as the I read the OP's question he wants 0 or 1 spaces?

Comment: I am using this match regex

keyword.match(/\s{0,1}>\s{0,1}/g)

But I don't want to match in case the '>' character is present at start or end> 
How can I modify this regex to achieve this

e.g.  motor>    --- should fail
      >motor    --- should fail
      motor >    --- should pass
      > motor    --- should pass
      motor > car  ----  should pass
      motor >car  ----  should fail
      motor> car  ----  should fail

Comment: @M42:  This is not working in case of 'motor >' and '> motor'. This should pass. It should fail if there is no space 'motor>' and '>motor'

Comment: @M42: I also want to be as good as u in regex. How can I achieve that? and if there are any ddocuments or sites that are helpful please share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bramha: here are usefull sites: http://www.rexegg.com/ and http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2):

You can make your regular expression like so:

```
/ ?> ?/g
```

What we do here is saying if you find > with 0 or 1 space before then match.
(the ? operator stands for 0 or 1)

Comment: It is probably better to use \s as a white space because of Unicode white space characters (ref.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429146/javascript-regular-expression-single-space-character)

Comment: I agree, however the OP asked for an optimization, the \s is less optimized (same with the \d and \w) as it needs to test for more possible hits. Therefore I've chosen to just take the space. But indeed if he were testing on unicode documents he should use the \s instead.