# JavaScript: replace non breaking space and special space characters with ordinary space

Tags: javascript, string, ascii, non-breaking-characters

I was trying to debug a problem of searching inside a string and it came down to the following interesting piece of code.

Both `"item "` and `"item "` seem equal but they are not!

```js
var result = ("item " === "item ");

document.write(result);
console.log(result);
```

After investigating this further by pasting it on a Python interpreter, I found out that the first `"item "` has a different kind of space as `"item\xc2\xa0"`. Which I think is a [non breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Now, A possible solution to match these strings will be to replace `\xc2\xa0` with space, but is there a better approach to convert all special space characters with normal space?.

Comment: Check `"item ".charCodeAt(4)` of both strings. They are different

Comment: Yes, I have done that, and the characters are different as mentioned in the question. My question is on how to approach with comparing these strings? (without trimming/removing spaces)

Comment: I was just mentioning how to identity it without using python interpreter.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the possible space characters in Unicode here: https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=space there are also some language specific space characters. So this can get really tricky if you are perfectionistic.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly, Haha, thank you. I will definitely check that out. FYI, my perfectionistic parameter is at 90 percent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space in the first string is character code 160 (a non-breaking space), and the space in the second string is character code 32 (a normal space), so the strings aren't equal to each other.

```js
console.log("item ".charCodeAt(4), "item ".charCodeAt(4));
```

> is there a better approach to convert all special space characters with normal space?.

You can match space characters which aren't tabs or newlines and replace with a normal space:

```js
const makeSpacesNormal = str => str.replace(/(?=\s)[^\r\n\t]/g, ' ');
console.log(makeSpacesNormal("item ") === makeSpacesNormal("item "));
```

Specifically, the `\s` will match [a whole bunch of space-like characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429180):

```
[\t\n\v\f\r \u00a0\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u200b\u2028\u2029\u3000]
```

and by matching and replacing those (except newlines and tabs, if you want), you'll be left with ordinary spaces.

Comment: On regex101.com it says that: **\s** matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`. Which is wrong then?

Comment: You can see a description in the official specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-line-terminators) (scroll up a bit, and also scroll down - see the `WhiteSpace` and the `Line Terminator` table). I think Regex101 tried to simplify things for all languages rather than go into detail on the mechanics for each, not sure how precise it is for other languages

Comment: I will accept this answer because 1. Works cross-browser, 2. Is extensible, 3. Well detailed.

Answer (score 9):

In ES2015/ES6 you can use the [String.Prototype.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method to decompose both characters to the same simple space character:

```js
const normalize = str => str.normalize('NFKD');
console.log(normalize("item\u0020") === normalize("item\u00a0"));
```

Comment: Not supported by IE. :-D

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly yes, IE doesn't support much of ES2015... There is [this polyfil I didn't test myself](https://github.com/walling/unorm) though if support for IE is really needed.

Answer (score 0):

[`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) will remove all whitespace from the beginning and end of a string. If you want to compare two strings while ignoring leading and trailing whitespace, trim both of them.

```
"item ".trim() === "item ".trim()
```

Comment: But OP wants to *convert all special space characters with normal space*, not *remove* all leading/trailing spaces

Comment: I want to match the space too. It should not be true for "item" === "item "